# Node module similar with passportJS that offers oauth, local, and basic strategy authentications?

Tags: node.js, rest, oauth, passport.js, wp-api

Are there any node module that can compete with passportJS. Something that can provide **oauth1**, **oauth2**, **local** and **basic** authentication?

I've been trying to login to wordpress using wordpress API. I managed to login successfully using oauth2 but wordpress api dont recognize my credentials when trying to post. Wordpress API gave me an access token and request token, so this shows that wordpress allow my access.

```
{
    "message": "Successfully fetched profile",
    "user": {
        "_id": "5947b48f1befbd29f82fcffe",
        "refreshToken": "th21j1gpn4ybtiphxi3exfjys4j7g8gnbdfwguil",
        "accessToken": "mi8vbwlosv0gbbr4mokc1gvwixqwuvwmc7cefluq",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

I also tried oauth1 but node keep giving me a "Failed to obtain request token error". I've check the keys and secret like twenty times but still this error.

```
 passport.use(new OAuth1Strategy({
        requestTokenURL     : configAuth.oauth1.requestTokenURL,
        userAuthorizationURL: configAuth.oauth1.userAuthorizationURL,
        accessTokenURL      : configAuth.oauth1.accessTokenURL,
        consumerKey         : configAuth.oauth1.consumerKey,
        consumerSecret      : configAuth.oauth1.consumerSecret, 
        callbackURL         : configAuth.oauth1.callbackURL,
        signatureMethod     : configAuth.oauth1.signatureMethod
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
        BlogUser.findOne({ 'id': profile.id }, (err, user) => {
            if (err)
               return done(err);
            if (user) {
               return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
            } else {

                var newBlogUser = new BlogUser();

                newBlogUser.id = profile.id;
                newBlogUser.accessToken = accessToken;
                newBlogUser.refreshToken  = refreshToken;

                // save our user to the database
                newBlogUser.save(err => {
                   if (err){
                       console.log(err);
                       throw err;
                    }
                    // if successful, return the new user
                    return done(null, newBlogUser);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
));
```

Then here's keys

```
'oauth1' : {    
    'requestTokenURL': 'http://samplesite.com/oauth1/request',      
    'userAuthorizationURL':'http://samplesite.com/oauth1/authorize',
    'accessTokenURL': 'http://samplesite.com/oauth1/access',
    'consumerKey': '5K1Zld******',
    'consumerSecret': 'egTJf2ct3NDzzmEPrXP***************************',
    'callbackURL': 'http://127.0.0.1:3003/auth/wordpress/callback',
    'signatureMethod': 'HMAC-SHA1'
},
```

I want to try different modules other than passport to see if I will get the same error with oauth.

Comment: Could you please clraify your question. Are you interested in alternatives to PassportJS? Or do you need help with setting up PassportJS?

Comment: I'm interested with alternatives of passportJS. I'm just stating my problem to tell others why I want to try something other than passport. 

I've edited my question. Thanks for the response mate.